# What is the most secure key exchange method

Tags: cryptography

I have developed my own system similar to ssl and at the moment im using this key exchange method:

1. Server generates a RSA public-private key pair and sends public key to client
2. client generates an AES key and encrypts using servers public key and sends to the server
3. the server decrypts and now both ends have a shared secret key

I just want to know if this is secure and if there are any proper methods out there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming by crypto - see crypto.stackexchange.com.

Comment: there are so many implementation details to get wrong when doing this sort of thing.  why not just use SSL or TLS or something that has been battle hardened?

Comment: Oh, so you invented hybrid cryptography?

Comment: You see im not developing a protocol to use in real life im just interested in these things and want to try to make as strong as possible as i can

Comment: @JojoTheCodeDude the way to do that is to explore existing protocols and analyzing them, otherwise you step in each of the many mistakes that SSL made *alone* (and that protocol was constructed by relative experts!). Starting from scratch and asking about every decision so you have to *argue* rather than to look things up is not the right thing to do, and off topic on any SE site (including cryptography, where I'm mod).

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not secure. Specifically, it's vulnerable to a *man-in-the-middle* attack, where an eavesdropper hijacks the connection between the client and server.

```
+--------+                         +---------+                         +--------+
|        | <---(RSA pub key B)---- |         | <---(RSA pub key A)---- |        |
| CLIENT |                         | M.I.T.M |                         | SERVER |
|        | -------(AES key)------> |         | -------(AES key)------> |        |
+--------+                         +---------+                         +--------+
```

To the client, the man in the middle behaves just like the server. It sends the client an RSA public key (`RSA pub key B`) and receives an AES key from the client. What it can then do is contact the server to obtain a genuine RSA key (`RSA pub key A`) from the actual server, and send it the same AES key.

Since the man in the middle now has the AES key, it can read all the traffic between the client and server.

As others have hinted in the comments, your first mistake occurred here:

> I have developed my own system similar to ssl

Don't do that. Use existing cryptosystems and protocols. Don't invent your own.

In this case, you should be using HTTPS/TLS.

Answer (score 0):

in partial answer to your question:

> I just want to know if this is secure

you should note that nothing "is secure".  The best you can do is not being "vulnerable" to existing/well-known/published attacks, and hoping that nobody has any attacks they're keeping secret that you'd be vulnerable to.

Learning by experimenting can be good, but reading up on existing attacks can be a better use of time.  Here are a few potentially relevant links:

- https://www.crypto101.io/, via https://diagprov.ch/crypto-reading-list.html which has lots of other suggestions
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7457 contains a summary of known attacks on TLS, while https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246 describes TLS1.2 and discusses security issues throughout
- https://cve.mitre.org/cve/ documents published vulnerabilities and it might be useful to have a look at a few

in answer to:

> if there are any proper methods out there

yes, lots.  You just need to be much more specific.  Why/what is preventing you from using SSL/TLS at the moment?